# Java Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, quick-sort

I am trying to work on writing readable code and reducing the amount of redundant code I write. I find this hard to do especially when it comes to algorithms. So, I wrote a quicksort program to practice.

Is there any way I can improve this? I know in terms of efficiency it could be better (instead of taking the leftmost as the pivot, I could choose a pivot in the middle of the array). However, is there a way I could have declared or initialized things better or could I have used a more efficient method of checking different cases?

```
 package quicksort;

/**
 * @date December 4, 2015
 */
public class Quicksort {

   // private static int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 8, 1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5};
   private static int[] intArray = new int[]{11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    //private final static int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

    /**
     * @purpose This method partitions the array and subarrays based on the current pivot point
     * @param pivot
     * @param leftPointer
     * @param rightPointer 
     */
private static void partition(int pivot, int leftPointer, int rightPointer) {

    while (leftPointer <= rightPointer) {
        if (pivot < intArray[rightPointer]) {
            rightPointer--;
        } else if (pivot > intArray[rightPointer]) {
            intArray[leftPointer] = intArray[rightPointer];
            intArray[rightPointer] = pivot;
            leftPointer++;
        } else if (intArray[leftPointer] > pivot) {
            intArray[rightPointer] = intArray[leftPointer];
            intArray[leftPointer] = pivot;
            rightPointer--;
        } else {
            leftPointer++;
        }

    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= intArray.length - 1; x++) {
        System.out.print(intArray[x] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

/**
 * @purpose This method recursively runs the partition method for the array and subarrays
 * @param pivot
 * @param leftPointer
 * @param rightPointer 
 */
private static void quicksort(int pivot, int leftPointer, int rightPointer) {

    while (rightPointer != 0) {
        partition(intArray[0], 0, rightPointer);
        rightPointer--;
    }

    while (leftPointer != intArray.length - 1) {
        leftPointer++;
        partition(intArray[leftPointer], leftPointer, intArray.length - 1);
    }

}

/**
 * @purpose Runs the Quicksort class
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int leftPointer = 0;
    int rightPointer = intArray.length - 1;
    int pivot = intArray[0];
    quicksort(pivot, leftPointer, rightPointer);

}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! GOod job on your first question.

Comment: If you fix the bug noted in [@mjolka's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112956/71574), please post the revised code in a new question.

Comment: Okay. Do I need to delete this question then?

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in the code. If you try to sort

```
4, 3, 1, 2, 0
```

you get

```
0, 2, 1, 3, 4
```